# Why does this cause a segmentation error and that does not?

Tags: c

Why does this cause a segmentation error,

```
int main(char *argv[]) 
{
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

and why doesn't this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    printf("\ncmdline args count=%d", argc);

    /* First argument is executable name only */
    printf("\nexe name=%s", argv[0]);

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("\narg%d=%s", i, argv[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I don't get the difference. However I am a total noob in terms of C-programming.

Comment: The first one has an unsupported `main` definition

Comment: Is there any specific reason, why you want the first version to run? Just add the `int argc` in the definition, and it will work as expected. There is no need to use the `argc` variable if you don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one, presuming there is no valid implementation-defined behavior for it, has an unsupported definition of `main()`.

From the C11 Standard:

> **5.1.2.2.1  Program  startup**
>
> The function called at program startup is named main . The implementation declares no prototype  for  this 
>   function.   It  shall  be  defined  with  a  return  type  of int and 
>   with  no parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv , though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in
>   which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Answer (score 4):

The first program has an invalid prototype for `main`: `int main(char *argv[])`.

This has undefined behavior, which in your case is a crash.

The second program is correct and executes as expected.